# Mobile Application using Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Future loadModel() async {
try {
  final gpuDelegateV2 = tfl.GpuDelegateV2(
      options: tfl.GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
    false,
    tfl.TfLiteGpuInferenceUsage.fastSingleAnswer,
    tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minLatency,
    tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
    tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
  ));

  var interpreterOptions = tfl.InterpreterOptions()
    ..addDelegate(gpuDelegateV2);
  interpreter = await tfl.Interpreter.fromAsset('mobilefacenet.tflite',
      options: interpreterOptions);
} on Exception {
  print('Failed to load model.');
}
```

}

In the "false" there is an error said "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 5 found. (Documentation)  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments." How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/tflite_flutter/latest/tflite_flutter/GpuDelegateOptionsV2-class.html), the parameters you are trying to pass to the `GpuDelegateOptionsV2` constructor should be named.

So it should be instantiated as follows

```
tfl.GpuDelegateOptionsV2(
isPrecisionLossAllowed: false,
inferencePreference: tfl.TfLiteGpuInferenceUsage.fastSingleAnswer,
inferencePriority1: tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.minLatency,
inferencePriority2: tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
inferencePriority3: tfl.TfLiteGpuInferencePriority.auto,
)
```